# Dual-boot 12.04 on a computer already running Windows 7 - disk partition details

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I am a total beginner to the world of Ubuntu. I would like you people to help me on how to dual-boot 12.04 on a computer already running windows 7 Ultimate.

I have:

- dual core processor,
- 2GB RAM,
- 500GB hard disk with

  - c occupying 100GB (Windows is over here),
  - d having 180GB (all other stuff like movies, songs and stuff),
  - e having 185GB (totally empty).

I would like to install it on `e` by allocating 30GB (25 for root and 5 for swap) to it by partitioning the disk .

The problem is that when I select **Something Else** option it shows all the disks properly but when I select sda4 i.e. local disk `e`, the `Add` option does not respond. Only `Change` option responds on that window.

I'm totally confused. Please help me on that. Is GParted a good option? If yes, then please elaborate. If possible please provide screen-shots of everything.

Answer (score 1):

You may have 4 primary partitions, the maximum allowed.

After you select "Something Else" change `sda4` from **primary** to **extended**. Inside the extended partition create three logical partitions, one for root `/` (25GB), one for swap (5GB) and one for `/home` (rest).

Partition types for  `/` and `/home` should be ext4 and swap should be swap.

The rest should be easy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum primary partition allowed is only 4 partitions on each drive. Try making logical partition that allows you to create way more partition than primary and I will recommend you to move your partition that without OS (for data only) to logical to easily manage your drive. I will use Gparted from the live cd instead of the installation one, because it's **MAYBE** more safety and more user friendly.